# Spacemacs laggy without external keyboard

Tags: spacemacs

I recently installed Spacemacs on my laptop and I notice strange bahaviour; 
if I'm using it with external keyboard everything is fine but soon as I use laptop without external keyboard Spacemacs became really laggy, there is visible delay between me pressing key and letter appearing on screen.
I really can't understand what could be reason for such behaviour, all other applications behave same.
I'm using Vim for years (there is no visible difference between using it with or without external keyboard on same laptop) and really like Spacemacs but this is actually show stopper for me since I use laptop without external keyboard a lot.

UPDATE:

Based on some other posts about slow Emacs/Spacemacs I removed **linenum** option and after that everything is just fine! What I still don't understand why there is difference in Spacemacs behavior depending on being on power supply or not??? (If I'm on power supply and turn on linenum option application work fine, if I unplugged laptop Spacemacs suddendly become very slow)

Comment: Does the lag disappear if you start Emacs without any user configuration -- aka `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Not really sure how to do that? I'm using Spacemacs on Windows 10. But actually one thing pop-up to mind now, it is laggy when I'm using it as laptop on battery. On the other side when I'm using it with external keyboar it is allways on power supply. Could this maybe have something with slowness?

Comment: Create a Windows shortcut to the program `runemacs`, and put this in field **Target**: `<YOUR-PATH-TO-WHERE-EMACS-IS>\bin\runemacs.exe -Q`. Then use that shortcut to start Emacs without any init file.

Comment: I'm not at a Windows computer at the moment, but you might try something like this.  If you have an icon on your desktop, create a shortcut for it.  Once created, right click the shortcut and select "Properties".  I believe there is a field for "Target" or something like that.  If you're able to append to that field, put the `-Q` there, press OK, and double-click the shortcut.  If that doesn't work, but you see a target, open a command prompt by pressing `Windows` and typing `cmd`.  Use `cd` to navigate to the target directory.  Once there, type whatever the target `.exe` is plus `-Q`.

Comment: @simkestuff Have you tried Spacemacs while on external power?

Comment: @Sam Yes, and then everything work just fine!

Comment: When you unplug power supply, your laptop is probably going into some sort of energy saving mode. The CPU is then not working full speed. Check energy settings in windows.